# LibreOffice java uno 'How to get cursor position of text range or a paragraph'

Tags: java, libreoffice, uno

I'm looking for a clever and accurate way to get the cursor position of a paragraph within a text. I will be using this point to place an image besides the text items or paragraphs. I am doing this on impress and thus using XShape and XText. The position I'm looking for would be similar to XTextViewCursor's getPosition method. Below best describes what I'm looking for.

```
[position ?]  This is paragraph one

[position ?]  this is paragraph tow
              this is paragraph two

[position ? ] this is paragraph three
              this is paragraph three
              this is paragraph three
```